# jsoncpp - can't define Json::Reader due to incomplete type

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

Getting this error when I follow the simple code example from jsoncpp, that basically goes like

`Json::Reader reader;`

How to fix this?  The type looks pretty complete to me but it's not like g++ is nice enough to tell me what is missing or anything.

`error: aggregate Json::Reader reader has incomplete type and cannot be defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was supposed to `#include <json.h>`, not the individual classes I needed, per the `README.txt`.